# Dropdown menu loses background gradient during fade-out

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions, transition

I've coded a dropdown menu with HTML and CSS, and I can sucessfully have it fade in when the user's mouse hovers over the button in the menu. However, when the mouse leaves the dropdown, the dropdown fades out, except for the background of the dropdown.

**It's because the `height` of the container `div` with the background changes to zero immediately after the mouse leaves the dropdown.**

If I don't set the height to zero,

How can I get around this height issue with the `div`?

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.top-block-container {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.5% 0.25%;
}
.top-block-container:hover .top-block-dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  height: auto;
}
.top-block {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: background-color 0.25s linear, box-shadow 0.25s linear;
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CCCCCC, #AAAAAA);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-block:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
}
.top-block-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CCCCCC, #AAAAAA);
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  transition: visibility 0.25s, transform 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
}
.dropdown-option-heading {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
.dropdown-option {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.25s linear;
}
.dropdown-option:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, dodgerblue, #00B0FF);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.last-option {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-block-container">
  <h1 class="top-block">ECWMF</h1>
  <div class="top-block-dropdown">
    <p class="dropdown-option-heading">Global Models</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">GFS</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">ECMWF</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">CMC</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">NAVGEM</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">UKMET</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option-heading">Mesoscale Models</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">HRRR</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">HWRF</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">NAM 32km</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">NAM 12km</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">RAP</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">SREF</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option last-option">HIRESW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove "height: 0" from ".top-block-dropdown", and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 0` from `.top-block-dropdown` and make it `position: absolute`.

And make its parent `position: relative`.
Use `top, bottom, left, right` to move it.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.top-block-container {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.5% 0.25%;
  position: relative; /* add */
}
.top-block-container:hover .top-block-dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  /*height: auto;*/
}
.top-block {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: background-color 0.25s linear, box-shadow 0.25s linear;
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CCCCCC, #AAAAAA);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-block:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
}
.top-block-dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CCCCCC, #AAAAAA);
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /*height: 0;*/
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  transition: visibility 0.25s, transform 0.25s, opacity 0.25s linear;
  position: absolute; /* add */
  top: 100%; /* push so it appear after .top-block-container*/
}
.dropdown-option-heading {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
.dropdown-option {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.25s linear;
}
.dropdown-option:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, dodgerblue, #00B0FF);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.last-option {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-block-container">
  <h1 class="top-block">ECWMF</h1>
  <div class="top-block-dropdown">
    <p class="dropdown-option-heading">Global Models</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">GFS</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">ECMWF</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">CMC</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">NAVGEM</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">UKMET</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option-heading">Mesoscale Models</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">HRRR</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">HWRF</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">NAM 32km</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">NAM 12km</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">RAP</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option">SREF</p>
    <p class="dropdown-option last-option">HIRESW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```